# AlertInput handler never gets called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 with React and typescript.

I'm looking to create an alert with a email input and 2 buttons, "cancel" and "accept".

I want the "accept" button to only be available when the user is giving a valid email address. Therefore I want to use a regex in the input field handler, but the handler is never called, not when typing nor when pressing enter. How can I get it to get callled when the user is typing

```
async showAlert() {
  var promise = await alertController.create({
    header: "Recevez la photo dans votre boîte mail",
    inputs: [{
      name: "email",
      type: "email",
      placeholder: "email",
      handler: () => {
        console.log("input Fild Hanlder Called");
      }
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: "cancel",
        role: "cancel",
        handler: cancel => {
          console.log("cancel");
        }
      },
      {
        text: "envoyer photo",
        role: "send",
        handler: (alertData) => {
          console.log((/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test((alertData.email))));
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  await promise.present();
  let result = await promise.onDidDismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;tr** This feature is not implemented in ionic4: [ionic/issues/19059](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19059)

---

After comparing the ionic code for [rendering a checkbox in an alert](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/alert/alert.tsx#L333) and [any other input element](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/alert/alert.tsx#L363) I came to the sad conclusion that the feature you are looking for doesn't exist.

At the moment it looks like `handler` on input in alerts is only supported for checkboxes and radio-inputs

There [was a PR for ionic3](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/12541/commits/52e97b42b60ae133f8284839c04b08dce9c3c4e9#diff-de0d9cae46569fbae96547cd3c1b793c) that added the `validators` option to `AlertInputs` to provide angular form validation but its not there anymore in ionic4.

There is still an open issue for [ionic3 requesting input validation for alert inputs](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/228) but non for ionic4 as far as I can see.

---

**Update:** [new feature request for ionic4](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/228)